# Problem getting a BOOL from a SQLite DB

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm writing an app using a SQLite db to store information.  My db table includes 5 fields: gameID (the primary key, int), gameName (Varchar), isLocked, isHidden, and isFavorite (all bools).  I've set up the db using SQLite Manager in FireFox.

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

FightingGamesGuideAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FightingGamesGuideAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


        //My second thought is that this line is incorrect.  (see below)
    const char *sql = "select gameID, gameName, isLocked, isHidden, isFavorite from GameTable";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {


            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Games *coffeeObj = [[Games alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            //getGameName
            coffeeObj.gameName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            //I think these three lines are where the problem is
            coffeeObj.isLocked=(BOOL)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 2);
            coffeeObj.isHidden=(BOOL)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 3);
            coffeeObj.isFavorite=(BOOL)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 4);

              //This line is only to check if the data loaded properly
            NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i",isLocked, isHidden, isFavorite);


            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];

            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
}
else{
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}

}
```

My question: Is this how to get a bool from a SQLite db?  Is there a better way, such as using an int as a bool instead?  If my code is all correct, do you have any other suggestion for how I can do this?

I know that the code aside from those three lines (and the following line) work properly. In the db, I've randomly assigned the three bools to YES or NO.  I've also tried 1 and 0, to no effect.

If the lines are correct, my second thought is that line 9 is wrong.  I modified it from "const ... ="select gameID, gameName from GameTable", and gameID and gameName still work properly.

My third thought is that I'm not updating the db correctly.  I won't go into that, besides to ask if there's a specific "save" button/list item.  If I update a gameName, that shows in my app, suggesting the db saves automatically.

In looking through the other questions, I've only found suggestions that CoreData is a better idea.  However, if I'm on the right track, I only need these three lines to work, and I'm done (with this part).

Aside-I know that nothing is done with the bool variables besides printing them to the console.  That's my next challenge.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to p.campbell's answer (+1), you could recall your `BOOL` value like this if you are storing YES/NO in your DB:

```
  coffeeObj.isLocked=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)] isEqualToString:@"YES"];
  coffeeObj.isHidden=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)] isEqualToString:@"YES"];
  coffeeObj.isFavorite=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)] isEqualToString:@"YES"];
```

Comment: This appears to be working, thank you.  Can you shed any light on why my approach wasn't working? Thanks!

Comment: Well I haven't seen your YES/NO version of the code. In your current display of code I see you trying to ask for an int and cast it as a `BOOL`. I have never tried this and am uncertain if it would behave in the manner you are trying. I would need to test that. If it were me using int, I would still do a comparison that I was certain would generate a `BOOL`. `coffeeObj.isLocked=(sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 2) == 1);` But that's me. I will try your way and see what results I get.

Comment: I tested your use of `coffeeObj.isLocked=(BOOL)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 2);` and assuming your DB truly had an `int` stored, it looks like it should've worked. Maybe it is possible you had something else tweaked wrong?

Comment: Got it.  I'd set the db column as a BOOL, but entered YES/NO and 1/0, rather than changing it to an INTEGER column.  Duh.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLite datatypes page](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) has the answer you're looking for:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  I did find that page.  My question was meant to be something more like "Why isn't what I'm doing working."  By converting to a BOOL from an int, I assumed that I was working around that issue.  SQLite Manager add on for FireFox has a Boolean option, thus my experiment with YES/NO vs 1/0. Thanks, though.