# Bool value from SQLite always returns 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

In my SQLite table I have a column 'hasSubCountries' which supposed to store simple 0/1 value cos SQLite [doesn't has distinct boolean type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean).

While digging in stackoverflow I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165183/problem-getting-a-bool-from-a-sqlite-db), but it didn't solve my problem.

At moment in my database I have column:

```
hasSubCountries integer DEFAULT 0
```

Have changed the value of the couple of subCountries to 1.

And DBAccess class I try to read the value into object:

```
countryObj.hasSubCountries=(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6) == 1);
```

In viewController code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Country* country = [[self.countries objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if(country.hasSubCountries==1)
    {

    SelectedCountry *selCountry=[[SelectedCountry alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectedCountry" bundle:nil];
    [selCountry setTitle:@"Country"];
    [selCountry setCountryID:country.countryID];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selCountry animated:YES];
    [selCountry release];
    }
else
    {
    SubCountries *subCountries=[[SubCountries alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubCountries" bundle:nil];
    [subCountries setTitle:@"Sub"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:subCountries animated:YES];
    [subCountries release];
    }

NSLog(@"%d ... %d",country.hasSubCountries,country.countryID);
}
```

Well, NSLog says me that anyway I'm getting 0, and that's why 'if' pushes  me to @"Sub". **Where I went wrong?**

The name and ID of country I am getting without problem. See screenshot

[image]

Full table definition:

[image]

Comment: can you add your full table column definitions?

Comment: also, is hasSubCountries a BOOL?

Comment: @bryanmac hasSubCountries integer DEFAULT 0

Comment: can you share the select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be column index 7?

0 countryID
1 countryName
2 relativeToContinent
3 countryFlag
4 hasRegionalIssues
5 hasDifferentBankIssues
6 hasIssue
**7 hasSubCountries**

Try:

```
countryObj.hasSubCountries=(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7) == 1);
```

Not:

```
countryObj.hasSubCountries=(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6) == 1);
```

Comment: because the second arg to sqlite3_column_int is the column index.  According to your table definition, hasSubCountries is the 7 index column.  That is, if your doing select *.  If your sql statement is a different select statement with explicit columns (which you didn't share) then it may not be 7.

Comment: const char* sqlCountries =sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT countryID,countryName,countryFlag,hasRegionalIssues,hasDifferentBankIssues,hasIssue,hasSubCountries\
                       FROM countries\
    WHERE relativeToContinent=%i\
    ORDER BY countryName ASC",continentID);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reverse your thinking?

```
countryObj.hasSubCountries=(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6) != 0);
```

Comment: Sorry guys,

It's me an idiot (ashamed and hiding eyes). Sorry for wasting your time. I am just forgot to select these fields in my SQLite select query. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those ones are really strings. Open the database using the `sqlite3` command line program, and try running `select hasSubCountries = 1 from countries`. Then try `select cast(hasSubCountries as integer) = 1 from countries`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,

It's me an idiot (ashamed and hiding eyes). Sorry for wasting your time. I am just forgot to select these fields in my SQLite select query. Everything works fine.